# Image wont become non-opaque when hovered over jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need these two images to fade in when hovered over and fade out when not hovered over. I've looked for hours, but nothing has worked.

What I have presently:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tut_select").mouseenter(function(){
            $(".tut_select").css("opacity","1");
        });
        $("#tut_select").mouseleave(function(){
            $(".tut_select").css("opacity",".8");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The page: http://pinkpencil.x10.mx/tutorials.php

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PinkPencil/TwyE8/

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.
You don't have jquery installed

Comment: well to start, there is no `$("#tut_select")` element on that page.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no absolute reason to use jQuery, why don't you do it with some CSS?

Example:

```
img.tut_select {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

img.tut_select:hover {
    opacity: .8;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it fade in using css? Because that just makes it change instantly. I need it to slowly do it.

Comment: OP, you would add CSS3 transition markup and adjust the speed parameter to get the desired result

Comment: @PinkPencil Have a look at the edit for the transitions suggested by IndieRok.

Comment: Ah, I found one. Thanks for the tip to just use css!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img class="tut_select" src="./images/desktop.png">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap { opacity:0 } 
.wrap:hover { opacity:1 }
```